# Flutter hangs when trying to get response from API

Tags: flutter, dart, http, freeze

I have a long string of around 1042 characters stored in the database, I tried hitting API to retrieve this string, when I ran it in Postman it worked, but when I hit request in flutter the application suddenly stopped and froze.

there's no error printed on console, it just hangs.

This is the code:

```
  @override
  Future<ResponseAPI> getPrivacyPolicy() async {
    try {
      Dio http = await dio();
      Response response = await http.get("/setting/type", queryParameters: {
        "type": 7,
      });

      final data = response.data;
      return ResponseAPI.fromJson(data);
    } on DioException catch (e) {
      if (e.response?.statusCode == 403) {
        return ResponseAPI(
          message: e.response?.data['message'],
          statusCode: 403,
        );
      } else {
        return const ResponseAPI(
          message: "There's something wrong, please try again later",
          statusCode: 500,
        );
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return const ResponseAPI(
        message: "There's something wrong, please try again later",
        statusCode: 500,
      );
    }
  }
```

and here's the response in Postman:

[image]

Comment: Is there an error code thrown during this process?

Comment: what is the error code thrown by Flutter ?

Comment: there's no error, the app just freeze and nothing print on console

Answer (score 0):

Try defining responseType for the Dio request Options

```
  options: Options(
      method: 'GET',
      responseType: ResponseType.plain,
   ),
```

Also, check for any exception thrown on the runtime environment or by using try and catch

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it didn't have any effect, 
idk why the app just hangs when i hit that API

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make a model

```
class SettingModel {
   String title;
   String content;
   InstitutionIdModel institution;

   SettingModel(this.title, this.content, this.institution);

   factory SettingModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => SettingModel(
         json['title'],
         json['content'],
         json['institution'],
       );
}

class InstitutionIdModel {
   int id;
   String name;
   String email;
   String? level;

   InstitutionIdModel(this.id, this.name, this.email, this.level);

   factory InstitutionIdModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
       InstitutionIdModel(
         json['id'] as int,
         json['name'],
         json['email'],
         json['level'],
       );
}
```

Then you have to make a model as follows

```
Dio http = await dio();
Response response = await http.get("/setting/type", queryParameters: {
"type": 7,
});


return response.data['responseData'].map<SettinModel>((json)=>SettinModel.fromJson(data)).toList();
```

Comment: yes, I have a model and the parsing function,
the problem is, it didn't even show the error or any console print, it just freeze but when i test it on postman it worked

Comment: I think the problem is with the request, the problem is with converting the response to the model

`final data = response.data;
 return ResponseAPI.fromJson(data);`

And if you don't have a print that wants to be printed, it is better to set a breakpoint to debug the program.
`return response.data['responseData'].map<SettinModel>((json)=>SettinModel.fromJson(data)).toList();‍`


Paste the codes I gave above and let me know if it was useful or not

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).